# How do I read the .txt file and run the query to insert the records?

Tags: sqlite, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a `.txt` file with an insert query of approximately 10,000 records. Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES
(1, '001034066', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 SB(E-TRONIC)(URB.) DIES 2P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 2, 'DIES', 1), 
(2, '001034078', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(RODOV.) DIES 1P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 1, 'DIES', 0), 
(3, '001034080', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(RODOV.C/AR) DIES 1P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 1, 'DIES', 0), 
(4, '001034091', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(URBANO) DIES 2P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 2, 'DIES', 0) ...
```

I would like to read the `.txt` file and run the query to insert all the records into the sqlite database.

I'm creating a table like this:

```
db.openDatabase({
  name: "data.db",
  location: "default"
}).then(() => {
  db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblVeiculo ("
    + "VeiculoId INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
    + "Codigo VARCHAR (512), "
    + "Fabricante VARCHAR (256), "
    + "Modelo VARCHAR (512), "
    + "AnoInicial DATETIME, "
    + "AnoFinal DATETIME, "
    + "[Portas] INT (1), "
    + "Combustivel VARCHAR (256), "
    + "[NrMotorObstruido] INT (1)); ", {}).then((data) => {
      console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", data);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error("Unable to execute sql teste", error);
    })
}, (error) => {
  console.error("Unable to open database", error);
});
```

How do I read the `.txt` file and run the query to insert the records in SQLite?

Comment: Maybe [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998559/how-to-read-a-text-file-that-was-downloaded-locally-ionic-2-and-cordova) or [**this**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/load-a-text-file-as-a-string-in-ionic-2/73180/2) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically read a text file and insert it into SQL server side so its peculiar that this is an Angular2 question.

This task should be done in your backend on startup.

However, if you wish to read a text file in angular2 you would first load it using the http service. Once loaded you might have difficulty talking to SQL client side. Even if you could, everyone would be able to see your code which would be insecure.